# Get Image from the Gallery and Show in ImageView

Tags: android, android-intent, imageview, android-gallery

I need to get an image from the gallery on a button click and show it into the imageview.

I am doing it in the following way:

```
    btn_image_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getImageFromAlbum();
        }
    });
```

The method Definition is as:

```
   private void getImageFromAlbum(){
    try{
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
    }catch(Exception exp){
        Log.i("Error",exp.toString());
    }
}
```

The activity result method is

```
  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        try {
            bmp = getBitmapFromUri(selectedImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        image_view.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        //to know about the selected image width and height
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, image_view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth()+" & "+image_view.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

---

### The Problem

The problem I am facing is when the image resolution is high suppose that if the image size is of 5mp to 13mp. It won't loads up and show up into the image view.

But the images with the low width and height are successfully loading into the image view!

Can somebody tell me any issues with the code and what I am doing wrong? I just want to import the camera images from the gallery and show them in the image view!

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Comment: do you get an error?or it just doesn't load the image?

Comment: it just doesn't load the image without any error!

Comment: @antonio I just want to import an image and show in imageview what to do with the bitmap?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

you can try this.

paste this code in your button click event.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

and below code is your on activity result

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }else {
            Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

I hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: getting rotated image?

Comment: Yes I'm facing the same problem.The image is randomly rotated.

Comment: If you have rotation problem check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64013845/8491926

Comment: startActivityForResult is deprecated

Answer (score 25):

I use this code:
This code used to start gallery activity.

```java
 Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
 startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
```

And get the result in:

```java
 @Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
         switch (requestCode){
             case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                 Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                 try {
                     Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                     carImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     Log.i("TAG", "Some exception " + e);
                 }
                 break;
         }
     }
```

And don't forget to declare permission in AndroidManifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Thank you Anton for providing an answer on StackOverflow. You can do a great deal for the quality of your answer by explaining the steps or the reasons for them. Still, have an upvote.

Comment: @D.Desai Do you use this in Fragment? If you want use this code in activity delete "getActivity()"

Comment: @Anton This one worked for me, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Because *OnActivityResult* method is deprecated, proper way nowadays with AndroidX Activity, is *Activity Result APIs*, and that recommended way, [see docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result)

"*registerForActivityResult()* takes an *ActivityResultContract* and an *ActivityResultCallback* and returns an *ActivityResultLauncher* which you’ll use to launch the other activity."

```
ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
    new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
            previewImage.setImageURI(uri);
        }
     });
```

And simply call

```
mGetContent.launch("image/*");
```

when needed.

Answer (score 3):

**startActivityForResult()** is **deprecated**. Android introduced **Activity Result Api** for same purpose.

This is how to implement **Activity Result**

```
 ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> imagePickerActivityResult = registerForActivityResult(
        new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    Uri imageUri = result.getData().getData();
                    Glide.with(this)
                    .load(imageUri)
                    .into(R.id.profileImageView);
                }
            }
        }
);
```

Call above code by calling launch() with intent

```
 Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
 galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
 imagePickerActivityResult.launch(galleryIntent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I try all  the solutions above but they don't work for me . I saw a code from **tutorialspoint** website and it works for me very well this is the code :

```
    final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button33);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
             MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
             startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
        }
    });


   @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri imageUri;
    ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_main_galary);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && reqCode == 100){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
    }
```

the most important issue : don't forget **PERMISSION** :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```