# Set Pixel of Bitmap caught by intent picker

Tags: android, bitmap, pixel, editing

my little App causes a crash when I try to set the Pixels of an **Bitmap loaded by the photopicker intent** and I cant figure out why. For the intent I took [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38352844/9942225).

So here is the important part of my current code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private Bitmap selectedImage;

  ...

  private void changebitmap() {

        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        for(int x = 0; x < selectedImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < selectedImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                selectedImage.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(255, 128, 128 ,128));
            }
        }

        imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);

  }
}
```

I can't figure out why it won't work.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just got it by myself.

The Problem was that the Bitmap from the intent hadn't the right Config.

On API Level 19 it says you can just set it by

```
selectedImage.setConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
```

On lower levels (like me) you can copy it pixelwise to another Bitmap with the right configuration.

```
selectedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(copy.getWidth(), copy.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

for(int x=0; x < copy.getWidth(); x++) {
  for(int y=0; y < copy.getHeight(); y++) {

    selectedImage.setPixel(x, y, copy.getPixel(x, y));

  }
}
```

Regards