# How to upload profile photo to app in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[image: This is what my UI looks like.]

I want the user to be able to access their gallery (by clicking the add photo ImageView), upload a photo of their choosing, and display that photo in the circular profile photo spot. I can't seem to find any definitive guides on how to do this. What is the easiest/best way to go about it? (in Java).

Comment: https://androidmyway.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/selecting-image-from-gallery-or-taking-image-from-camera-with-options-menu-uploading-to-server/

Answer (score 0):

(I would have commented, but I can´t, since I do not have 50 rep.)

You might wanna check:
[Get Image from the Gallery and Show in ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352148/get-image-from-the-gallery-and-show-in-imageview)

(Keep in mind that this is only about loading the Image, saving would need some extra)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to pick your photo:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

and below code is your on activity result:

```java
    @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    
    
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                    final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                    final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                    image_view.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
    
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(PostImage.this, "You haven't picked Image",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```